# why does client reconnecting leads to double connections with netty

Tags: java, netty

Client reconnects to server when connection is closed with Netty. But every time when connection is lost, client will reconnnect using two threads. Reconnection leads to double connections. How can I solve the problem?

```
public class ImConnection {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImConnection.class);
    private static Bootstrap b;
    private Channel channel;

    static {
        b = new Bootstrap();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        b.group(workerGroup);
        b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
        b.handler(new ConnectionInitializer());
    }

    public Channel connect() {
        doConnect(PropertyConstant.cfgcServerIP, PropertyConstant.cfgcServerPort);
        return this.channel;
    }
    private void doConnect(String host, int port) {
        try {
            ChannelFuture f = b.connect(host, port);
            f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                    if (!future.isSuccess()) {
                        final EventLoop loop = future.channel().eventLoop();
                        loop.schedule(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    connect(); // reconnect if fail
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    } else {
                        logger.info("connected");
                    }
            }});
            channel = f.channel();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

handler initializer

```
public class ConnectionInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<Channel> {

    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast(new ConnectionHandler());
    }
}
```

handler to reconnect when connection is lost

```
public class ConnectionHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    private ImConnection imConnection = new ImConnection();

    // get executed when connection drops
    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.err.println("connection lost");
        final EventLoop eventLoop = ctx.channel().eventLoop();
        eventLoop.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imConnection.connect();
            }
        }, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        super.channelInactive(ctx);
    }
}
```

Comment: How ImConnecton() class get ChannelHandlerContext to create event loop? I think you are calling connect() & reConnect() call on two different event loops, Hence two threads(event loop thread) create two connections

Comment: @OomphFortuity Once connection lost, thread 1 tries to connect and listener waits for the connecting result. If connecting fails, the listener fires a new connection task. I can't find two conncurrent connecting.

Comment: You are calling connect() in T1 and Listener calling reconnect() in T2. Example T1's connection fails it reconnects on T2 with its Listener calling reconnect() in T2. Here you have two open threads T1 and T2. Again it fails then you can see two connections.

Comment: You are calling connect() in T1 and Listener calling reconnect() in T2. Example T1's connection fails it reconnects on T2 with its Listener calling reconnect() in T2. Here you have two open threads T1 and T2. Again it fails then you can see two connections because your Bootstrap will have two Listeners for reconnect()

Comment: @OomphFortuity I think T1 will `connect()` just once, fail or succeed. And its listener gets executed to re-connect when T1 `connect()` fails.